# Reference to row in JTable

Tags: java, hashmap, jtable

JTable stores rows which can be added, deleted, shuffled, dynamically. In my implementation row represent a `Download`, whose progress can be dynamically updated, by passing value of one of the unique attribute called `id`. But how do I map `id` with actual row?

Iterating over the column is not efficient approach. Is there any way to dynamically synchronize `Hashmap<ID,Object[]>` with `JTable`, such that given a key I can update corresponding row, and vice versa?

```
private dftTasks=new DefaultTableModel();
public void addTask(String type, String name, int progress, int sessionID) {
    Object[] rowData={type,name,new Integer(progress),new Integer(sessionID)};      
    dftTasks.addRow(rowData);
}

public void updateProgress(int sessionID, int progress) {
    int i = dftTasks.getRow(sessionID); //<--alternative to this method
    dftTasks.setValueAt(new Integer(progress), i, 2); //2nd column=Progress
}
```

Comment: Try a concurrent hash map to store the values, and as for the array, I believe that there is an atomic array, and use a custom implementation of the TableModel instead of using the DefaultTableModel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257309/how-to-use-hashmap-with-jtable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a class to encapsulate the data (eg `type`, `name`, `progress`, and `id`).
2. Store instance of (1) in a `List`, and if necessary any other data structure for quick access (eg a `Map` keyed by id). The order of this `List` is the row order of the table.
3. Extend `AbstractTableModel`, and implement the necessary methods to return the values from the `List` from (1) and (2) based upon the row/column.
4. When values of the instances from (2) are changed (eg, the progress updated), call fireXXX from within the implementation in (3) (the source of `DefaultTableModel` is a good example of how this is done)

Answer (score 1):

You just answered your own question - use HashMap:

```
private dftTasks=new DefaultTableModel();
Hashmap<Integer,Object[]> map = new Hashmap<Integer,Object[]>();
public void addTask(String type, String name, int progress, int sessionID) {
        Object[] rowData={type,name,new Integer(progress),new Integer(sessionID)};
        map.put(progress,rowData);      
        dftTasks.addRow(rowData);
    }

    public void updateProgress(int sessionID, int progress) {
        //int i = dftTasks.getRow(sessionID); //<--alternative to this method
        Object[] i = map.get(sessionID);
        dftTasks.setValueAt(new Integer(progress), i, 2); //2nd column=Progress
    }
```

To do vice versa and listen for changes use [TableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html) to listen for the changes,

Comment: Modern Java has [Autoboxing]( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) which does the trick

Comment: Autoboxing converts
>between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes
Here Object[] is NOT wrapper..

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I blindly copied OP line of code and didn't pay attention that it was wrong. Now it is fixed.